# Laravel Generate key for decrypt password

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am working on a code

```
if (!function_exists('decrypt_password')) {
    function decrypt_password( $iv, $value)
    {
        $key = config('services.decrypt.key');

        $string_iv =hex_to_string($iv);
        $encrypter = new Encrypter($key, 'AES-256-CBC');

        $dec['iv'] = base64_encode($string_iv);
        $dec['value'] = $value;
        $dec['mac'] = hash_hmac('sha256',  $dec['iv'] . $dec['value'], $key);
       
        return ($encrypter->decrypt(base64_encode(json_encode($dec)),false));
    }
}
```

this piece of code should make a layer of decrypting the password, and key is missing in config and I can't get one or generate a new one.
any help!
edit: I tried to set 32 char key like "22222222222222222222222222222222" and got a new error `The payload is invalid`

Comment: You could make a function that creates and stores the new key in the env and the result of the function is the new key. That way, if it doesn't exist, it is created and you return it on the fly.

Comment: @ManuelGuzman okay, can you lead me to the way to generate valid keys?

Comment: That's up to you. It depends on what type of key are you expecting from config ```$key = config('services.decrypt.key');```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in `decrypt` the logic should encrypt.